# Programming with dplyr; quo, enquo, !!, etc

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm getting strange errors while trying to use dplyr with functions. I'm following the "[Programming with dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)" guide but I'm seeing strange errors. This is the example code I am basing my own program off of:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  g1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  g2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
  a = sample(5), 
  b = sample(5)
)


my_summarise <- function(df, group_var) {
  df %>%
    group_by(!!group_var) %>%
    summarise(a = mean(a))
}

my_summarise(df, quo(g1))
```

The example code should return

```
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      g1        a
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1 2.500000
#> 2     2 3.333333
```

But instead returns

```
Error: invalid argument type
Called from: mutate_impl(.data, dots)
```

Is there something wrong or a package I'm missing? I also observe this error when I follow the linked guide's later directions and call `my_summarise(df, g1)` instead, using `enquo(group_var)` inside the function.

**EDIT: Error occurs on older versions of dplyr. Above does not throw error for dplyr 0.7.4**

Comment: You may check your dplyr version as it works for me with `dplyr_0.7.4`

Comment: ah yes thanks! I was running 0.5.0 it's a version issue